# how to display multiple list objects using simplelist adapter in android

Tags: java, android, listadapter, simpleadapter, json

this is not working i would like to append the second SimpleAdapter over the 1st SimpleAdapter. but , it is getting overwritted and only the second list is being displayed.

I want to display both in a single list with different list format for each objects as list_item and list_item_new
need help

```
    ListAdapter newAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        NotificationTask.this, notificationsList,
                        R.layout.list_item_new, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME, TAG_DESCRIPTION},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.description });

                newAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                          NotificationTask.this, oldNotificationsList,
                          R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NID,
                          TAG_NAME, TAG_DESCRIPTION},
                          new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.description });

                //list.setAdapter(adapter);
                setListAdapter(newAdapter);

                        ((BaseAdapter) newAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: In addition to looking at some of the possible solutions below for your immediate problem, you really should take a look at first getting a firmer grasp of Java and probably programming in general as the fact that you are surprised at a value getting overwritten when you set a variable twice indicates some holes in your understanding of some basic programming concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, try to create a custom adapter able to handle both elements on the method getView (if one kind of view differs from the other).

The adapter is a middle man between the listview and its content, so each listview is able to manage just one adapter, this is the reason why it gets overwriten by the data located on the second adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I use `MatrixCursor` with `SimpleCursorAdapter` to combine multiple source of data to display.

You can override `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder`'s `setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex)` method and specify the logic.

[SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html)